# Display variable result in windows forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a variable name SN inside my main code that I want to display in a Textbox on a windows form.

I tried to call it in the textbox function but it's like it does not even exist outside the main, what can i modify so that i can access it on the form?

Here's my code:

```
public partial class Program : Form
{
    private Label label1;
    private TextBox textBox2;

    public bool testtrace()
    {   
        return true;
    }
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        String SN;
        F6CMarocTrazaWrapper test = new F6CMarocTrazaWrapper();
        var createdtime = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Users\saadf\Desktop\LeakKASALIS Logs\LeakTest 2707\Continuous 7_5_2018.csv");
        while(System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\saadf\Desktop\LeakKASALIS Logs\LeakTest 2707\Continuous 7_5_2018.csv"))
        {
            var Lastmodifiedtime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\Users\saadf\Desktop\LeakKASALIS Logs\LeakTest 2707\Continuous 7_5_2018.csv");  
            using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\saadf\Desktop\LeakKASALIS Logs\LeakTest 2707\Continuous 7_5_2018.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                if (Lastmodifiedtime > createdtime)
                {
                    DataTable dtbl = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(@"C:\Users\saadf\Desktop\LeakKASALIS Logs\LeakTest 2707\Continuous 7_5_2018.csv");
                    DataTable dttbl = Transposedatatable(dtbl);
                    InsertDataIntoSQLServer(dttbl);
                    createdtime = Lastmodifiedtime;
                    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-LNCGI78\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Testdatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
                    try
                    {
                        connect.Open();
                        SqlDataAdapter command = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 [20-SerialNo] FROM [dbo].[Table] ORDER BY [22-Time] DESC", connect);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        command.Fill(dt);
                        SN = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                        while (SN.Contains(","))
                        {
                            SN = SN.Replace(",", "");
                        }Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Program());

 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 41);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(95, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "SERIAL NUMBER";
        this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(225, 41);
        this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
        this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(239, 20);
        this.textBox2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.textBox2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox2_TextChanged);
        // 
        // Program
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(757, 387);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "Program";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: **[Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)**

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish here, but you should probably not be doing database operations in your `Main` function, and it is extremely unlikely you want `while(System.IO.File.Exists...` in your `Main`.

Comment: don't worry about these database operations,i just want to display the result of the SN string variable on a textbox in windows frame.@DourHighArch

Comment: Those database operations are what are messing you up, but your code is so confusing I can't even guess what you are trying to do. Maybe you want to put them in `Form_Load`? In a `Click` handler? Please get a book or follow a tutorial on Windows Forms development, this stuff is simply too complicated to learn by trial and error.